# Rabbitmq Consumer hangs when using PAMI open()

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

I have an rabbitmq consumer(oldsound) in a Symfony 2 project, when it consumes a message that should dispatch an event that makes a call to a PAMI Client->open(), for some reason every once in a while if the open() hangs or times out, the consumer is hung forever until we kill it and restart it.

Is there a way to make the consumer not wait for the event dispatcher in order to continue consuming messages as they arrive?

The problem can certainly be a PHP or PAMI related issue(however both have timeouts set but it does not seem to matter), but I am hoping to have the consumer continue anyway.

the following is in the EventListener that the consumer dispatches
PAMI is configured properly and has timeouts set, but if I add these print_r in the code,
on the times it hangs it never reaches "2 Opened" PHP does not seem to timeout and continue and neither does the PAMI Client.

```
print_r("1 Start");
$this->client->open();
print_r("2 Opened");
$callout = $this->client->send($originateMsg);
print_r("3 Sent");
```